# Let $a$ be a non-unit in a ring $R$. Show that $a$ lies in a maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $a$ be a non-unit in a ring $R$. Show that $a$ lies in a maximal ideal.

Is there a way to solve this without using Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: Commutative apparently?

Comment: You are, perhaps, only asking about commutative rings, but just in case I'd like to say that for noncommutative rings in general this is not true, even assuming Zorn's Lemma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; without Zorn's lemma, a ring may not have any maximal ideal. See [Zorn's lemma in abstract algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54194/zorns-lemma-in-abstract-algebra).